# How to trigger an event on focus out for a textfield in javafx using fxml?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have this function in the controller class of the relevant fxml. I need this function to be fired on focus out from a textfield, but scene builder doesn't have an event similar to onfocusout. How to achieve this using the control class?

```
@FXML
private void ValidateBikeNo(){
    Tooltip error = new Tooltip("This bike no exists");
    BikeNoIn.setTooltip(error);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can attach a focusListener to the TextField and then execute the code inside it. The listener can be attached inside the `initialize()` method of the controller.

```
public class MyController implements Initializable {
    ...
    @FXML
    private Textfield textField;

    public void initialize() {
        ...
        textField.focusedProperty.addListener((ov, oldV, newV) -> {
           if (!newV) { // focus lost
              // Your code
           }
        });
         .....
    }
}
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, click on the tick beside the answer.

Comment: It does not look like there is a way to do this in fxml as asked in the question vs the initialize of the controller. I do not think there is a xml attribute or child xml tag  like the onAction attribute for other nodes? Does anyone know if there is any kind of onUnfocus or equivalent ?

Answer (score 7):

You have to use method textField.focusedProperty() instead of textField.focusProperty

```
public class MyController implements Initializable { 
...         
@FXML        
private Textfield textField;
public void initialize() {
   textField.focusedProperty().addListener((ov, oldV, newV) -> {
      if (!newV) { // focus lost
              // Your code
           }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you repeat the accepted answer .. and even incorrectly?

Comment: because answer is literraly incorrect. there is no method focusProperty in the TextField class, so you you have to invoke textField.focusedProperty() instead of textField.focusProperty, what's wrong?

Comment: well ... now after you edited your answer (before it was just ... ehem...) that can be seen - anyway, it's a typo in the original, edit it (once you can, not entirely certain how much rep you need for that)

Comment: Kleopatra, I'm very sorry, I was trying to correct original answers, but system said that I cannot do that because corrected version of answer must be at least 3 characters difference. This is why I had to post new answer to help other guys find answer quicker, this is why. Sorry.