# What event fires when the focus leaves a TextArea control?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am using Scene Builder and don't see an event that would do this. There is "On Mouse Exited" : is that the one to listen for?

Comment: You can use x and y values ?

Comment: @bakero98 I don't follow.

Comment: does `public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue)` work for you ?

Comment: Not sure if this is similar to FXML (so i'm not flagging) but does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943652/how-to-trigger-an-event-on-focus-out-for-a-textfield-in-javafx-using-fxml help?

Comment: I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943652/how-to-trigger-an-event-on-focus-out-for-a-textfield-in-javafx-using-fxml

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

```
textArea = new TextArea();

textArea.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if (newValue){
                System.out.println("Textfield on focus");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Textfield out focus");
            }
    }
});
```

Happy coding!